# Make Spinner dropdown to match screen width

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, spinner

I'd like my Spinner dropdown items to fill the entire screen width even tho my 'title' does not. Problem is the dropdown menu width seems to be limited the Spinner's title width.

My goal is to make it fill the entire screen width, with no spacing left or right, right below the action bar. A similar one to what I'm trying to do would be Instagram's menu to change profile.

I looked to similar questions but didn't find a solution that worked here. Also tried to create a custom adapter and making sure its views had `match_parent` attribute on their width. But didn't work either.

**main.java** (only relevant part of the code for legibility)

```
mMyListsSpinner     = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_mylists);
ArrayAdapter<String> snipperAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            FamilistActivity.this, R.layout.layout_spinner_title, dummyLists);
snipperAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_spinner_dropdown);
mMyListsSpinner.setAdapter(snipperAdapter);
mMyListsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**layout_spinner_title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white_bright"
    android:maxLines="1"
    style="@style/OverflowMenu"
    android:text="this is my list"/>
```

**layout_spinner_dropdown.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_spinner_dropdown"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_actionbar_height"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textColor="@color/color_green_dark"
android:background="@color/color_white_bright"/>
```

**styles.xml** (only the relevant part)

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-15dp</item>
</style>
```

my toolbar:
**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bar_appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_actionbar_height"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
android:background="@color/color_green_bright">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_mylists"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    style="@style/OverflowMenu"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

By looking into AppCompatSpinner.java and running the debugger I saw in this line in `computeContentWidth()`

```
else if (mDropDownWidth == MATCH_PARENT) {
    setContentWidth(spinnerWidth - spinnerPaddingLeft - spinnerPaddingRight);
}
```

that SpinnerPaddingRight has a value that is not 0. I solved it by setting

```
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

in the Spinner view.

Comment: This solved my problem. I am surprised to see no one upvoting your answer. Well done..!!!